# Would negative 0 be an issue in this situation?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, division

I have a simple question that is motivated by safe coding.

I encountered a situation where I have to assign the negative value of the remainder of division or `0` to an `int` variable, so I used the following notation:

```
int a = -(b % c);
```

where both `b` and `c` are positive integers. The expression `(b % c)` will yield a positive number or `0` and `a` will be assigned the negative value of the result.

In the event that `(b % c)` yields `0`, what does `-0` evaluate to? `0` or negative `0`? and what are the implications if the latter happened?

P.S I don't know what negative `0` is.

Comment: You have to do `-1*(b%c)` most probably. And as far as I know there's no issue as its two's complement representation is the same for ints.

Comment: Two's complement notation cannot store `-0`, it is just `0`, but floating point variables *can* store `-0.0`.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero): "The widely used two's complement encoding does not allow a negative zero."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-(b % c)` cannot generate a negative 0 because C 2018 6.2.6.2 3 says:

> If the implementation supports negative zeros, they shall be generated only by:
>
> — the `&`, `|`, `^`, `~` , `<<` , and `>>` operators with operands that produce such a value;
>
> — the `+`, `-` , `*`, `/`, and `%` operators where one operand is a negative zero and the result is zero;
>
> — compound assignment operators based on the above cases.

Even if we interpret the above to include `-` as a unary operator, we have been given that `b` and `c` are positive integers, so `b % c` cannot produce a negative zero, so the operand to `-` in `-(b % c)` is not a negative zero.

If `==` is used to compare a negative zero and a non-negative zero, it produces true, as `==` operates based on the values of the operands, not their representations.

Negative zeros are extremely rare for integers in modern C implementations. Modern implementations overwhelmingly use two’s complement, which does not have a negative zero. Only specialized/historic/archaic implementations might use the alternative integer representations that have negative zeros (one’s complement and sign-and-magnitude). Floating-point representations commonly have negative zeros, but they are equal to positive zeros in comparisons for equality by value (the `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` operators).

Comment: Second paragraph about unary `-` seems odd to me. `b % c` cannot produce negative zero, but I don't think that was asked. It's unclear to me what point you are trying to make there.

Comment: @user694733: The question asks whether `-(b % c)` can produce negative zero. In that expression, `-` is a unary operator (original mistakenly said “unary operand”; I have corrected it). The quoted text of the C standard seems written to discuss binary operators in that second item, since it mentions “one operand,” suggesting there is more than one. However, even if we take it as applying to a unary operator, it says `-` can produce a negative zero only if its operand is a negative zero. Its operand cannot be a negative zero, as its operand is `b % c`, which does not produce negative zero here.